# C-Style for statement to Swift 3

Tags: swift2, swift3

I am stuck with this easy line but could not convert it from Swift 2 to Swift 3.

```
for(index = indexes.lastIndex;
    index != NSNotFound;
    index = indexes.indexLessThanIndex(index))
{

}
```

Comment: What language are you converting from? Is the original code written in Swift 2, in C, or in something else?

Comment: From swift 2, thanks

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be replaced with a `while` loop

```
var index = indexes.lastIndex
while index != NSNotFound {
  // do something with index
  index = indexes.indexLessThanIndex(index)
}
```